# How to show $\cos(\lambda^2)$ is non-negative definite?

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, statistics

The question is:

Is $\varphi(\lambda) = \cos(\lambda^2)$ a characteristic function of some distribution?

My attempt: The Bochner Theorem states that any continuous non-negative definite function which satisfies the normalization condition $\varphi(0)=1$ is the characteristic function of some probability measure.

So my idea is to prove that $\varphi(\lambda) = \cos(\lambda^2)$ is a non-negative definite.

The definition in my textbook is:

> A complex-valued function $f(\lambda)$ is said to be non-negative
> definite if for any $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_r$, the matrix F with
> entries $ F_{kl}= f(\lambda_k - \lambda_l)$ is non-negative definite,
> that is
>
> $(Fv,v) = \sum_{k,l= 1}^r (f(\lambda_k-\lambda_l)v_k \bar{v_l})\ge0$ for any complex vector $v_1,..., v_r$.

I now understand the complex exponential function $e^{iat}$ for any $a \in R$ is non-negative definite. What is the next step?

Comment: have you tried any $2\times 2$ examples?  E.g. $\lambda_1=0$ and say $\lambda_2=\omega$ where $\omega$ is a (generating) 4th root of unity.

Comment: @user8675309  $ 2\times 2$  matrix does not lead to a contradiction as it is of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &a\\ a &1\end{pmatrix}$$ where $-1\le a \le 1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I suppose you could say that you read "A complex-valued function ()" to mean that $f: \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ though it is very clear from my mention of $\omega$ that I read it as $f: \mathbb C\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ ; as $\cos$ is entire but the matrix has ones one the diagonal it could not be PSD in this case.  If OP had worked through the example this would have cleared up function domain issues.

Comment: @user8675309 The OP mentioned that the function $e^{iat}$ is positive definite for $a$ real. Certainly it is not positive definite if one allows complex arguments $t.$ Besides the absolute value of every positive definite function is bounded by its value at $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\mathbb{R}\ni\lambda\to \cos(\lambda^2)$ is nonnegative definite. By the [Bochner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) theorem there is a probability measure on the real line such that $$\cos(\lambda^2)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda t}\,d\mu(t)\quad (*)$$ Plugging in  $\lambda_n=(2n\pi)^{1/2},$ $n\ge 1$, we get $$1=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{i\lambda_nt}\,d\mu(t)$$ Taking real part gives
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty [1-\cos(\lambda_nt)]\,d\mu(t)=0$$ The integrated function is nonnegative.
Therefore the measure $\mu$ must be concentrated on the set $A_n$ of zeros of the function $t\mapsto 1-\cos(\lambda_nt)$ for every $n.$ We have  $$A_n=\left\{  {2k\pi \over \lambda_n}\,:\,  k\in \mathbb{Z}\right \}$$ Observe that  $A_1\cap A_2=\{0\}$ as the ratio $\lambda_2/\lambda_1=2^{1/2}$ is irrational. Thus $\mu$ is concentrated at $\{0\}.$ This leads to a contradiction, as the  RHS of $(*)$ is equal $1$ for every $\lambda.$

Comment: My bad. I have mixed up sine with cosine. I have re-edited. It should be fine now

Comment: I have re-edited. It should be crystal clear now.

Comment: Sorry, I still have some confusions. Can you explain "Taking real part gives" the integral 0? I know $e^{i \lambda_n t} = \cos(\lambda_n t)+ i \sin(\lambda_n t)$.

Comment: First take the real part of the first equality. The $\sin $ disappears. Then move the integral to RHS and use that $\mu$ is a probability measure

Comment: Oh I see your point. sin is odd function, that's why sin disappears. But what I know is from calculus. That is $i \int_\infty^\infty sinx dx$is 0. Here is not $dx$, it is $d\mu (x)$ instead. Can you tell me why it still vanishes?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the oddness, but with the fact that if two numbers are equal, then their real parts are equal. Besides the imaginary parts are equal as well.

Comment: I see. But why the integral is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos (\lambda_n t) d\mu(t)$ is real and why the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty i \sin (\lambda_n t) d\mu(t)$ is imaginary?

Comment: Because the parameter $\lambda_n$ is real, $\mu$ is real, $ t $ is real and do on. Hence both integrals are real. When you multiply a real number by $i$ you obtain a purely imaginary number.

Comment: $\mu$ is concentrated at {0}. Then how to get the contradiction? I don't quite understand "is concentrated" mean. Does that mean $\mu(t=0)=1$ since $\mu$ is a probability measure?

Comment: Yes. When $\mu(\{0\})=1$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})=0$  then $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda t}d\mu(t)=1$ for any $\lambda.$ This gives a contradiction, as $\cos(\lambda^2)$ is not a constant function.